# Folders on icloud.com are not on my computer

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud

I've just restored my MacBook Air.

On icloud.com, I can see all the folders and files I used to have on my computer before the restoration:

[image: My folders on icloud.com]

But locally I no longer have them:
[image: My folders locally]

**What can I do to make them appear on my Mac?**

Thanks for your help!

**edit:**
After four days, it finally appeared on my computer! Thank you all for your answers

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  As long as you're signed-in to the same iCloud account, it could many hours to sync the data back to your device.  The time will depend on many things, including your internet and wifi speed.  How long have you been waiting for the sync to complete?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the folders and files in iCloud I think that you can view them in iCloud. There you can click the download file next to the folders or files that you want back on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just restored your MacBook it could take several hours to sync depending on the size of the documents and your WiFi speed.

If after several hours it doesn’t sync, make sure you are signed in with the same Apple ID.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I restored it 24h ago and the WiFi is fast.

I am also signed in with the same Apple ID (my calendar and contacts are well-sync for instance)

Comment: @Ludmilaex same Apple ID? Go to system pretences iCloud and make sure iCloud Drive is on

Comment: same Apple ID, and iCloud Drive is on